# "Legacy Bios Implementation" - Should I update this or not?

Tags: 20.04, updates, bios, kvm-virtualization, emulation

The default Software Updater has received an automatic update for "Legacy BIOS Implementation:

[image]

As can be seen above, this is for updating from Ubuntu seabios version "**1.13.0-1ubuntu1**" to "**1.13.0-1ubuntu1.1**".

My question is, is this a safe/silent/automatic update, or will it involve anything like flashing the BIOS or re-installing the OS from a USB drive etc.? Is it like all the other usual updates or is something more involved?

The description for this update has this to say:

[image]

> **SeaBIOS is a legacy BIOS implementation, aimed at supporting not only emulated hosts such as QEMU, but also real hardware.
> Note, however, that SeaBIOS does not handle early initialization of core chipsets, so don't even think of flashing it to your board (look at Coreboot for that)**.

The wording seems to indicate that this update has something to do with hypervisors/hardware emulation - like the Android Studio Emulator or VirtualBox that I have installed.

My computer is working fine and I do not want to risk having to flash the BIOS or re-install the OS etc. If someone has experience with this kind of update, please advise me whether it is safe/risk-free. Is this a safe/silent/automatic update, and can I go ahead with this or not?

I have Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S,
the package `seabios` in Ubuntu is really only used for system emulation in `qemu` and `bochs`. If you are interested to dig deeper, here a [list of things depending on it](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-archive/germinate-output/ubuntu.focal/rdepends/seabios/seabios).
Installing/Upgrading this will not flash anything onto your real hardware.

Comment: Thank you, Christian!